# Initiating string with content of file (Swift)

Tags: swift, string, file

Swift newbie here. I am trying load a text file into a string using the following code:

```
var uncondString: String
if let tempstring = try? String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8) {
   uncondString = tempstring
}
print("\(uncondString)")
```

The print statement, however, throws error "Variable 'uncondString' used before being initialized"

I guess this is trivial for more experienced users but any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to add an `else` condition to your `if` statement

Comment: Thanks Leo, worked like a charm!

Comment: Note that you can also declare it using `let` if you won't change it in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the statement try? fails, it returns nil, and the if let statement is not executed when nil is returned

After all, this code is not a code that unconditionally succeeds in initialization, so a warning is displayed.

```
var uncondString: String
if let tempstring = try? String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8) {
    uncondString = tempstring
    print(uncondString)
}
```

or

```
let uncondString: String? = try? String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)
        
if let uncondStr = uncondString {
    print(uncondStr)
}
```